# Show dropdown elements dynamically depending upon other dropdown selection

Tags: angular, dynamic, dropdown, ngfor

I have 3 fields to add 3 Phone numbers.with every field there is a dropdown to select Phone number type(i.e Fax,Home,Mobile). 
When i select an option in dropdown1 (e.g Home), the next or both dropdowns should not show "Home" in it and so on. 
P.S All my dropdowns are being created dynamically thus i cannot have different data sources for all three dropdowns but can have only one data source.

I have tried removing the selected element from a temp data source but it also removes the selected option from dropdown1 too as their data source is same.

HTML

```
<div class="form-group row">
      <div class="col-md-6" formArrayName = "secondaryPhone">
        <div
        *ngFor = "let secondaryPhoneNumber of contactForm.get('secondaryPhone').controls; let i=index">
        <select (change)="onChangeSelectBox($event)">
          <ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="phoneList">
            <option *ngIf="showOption(item.id)" value="{{item.id}}">
              {{item.Name}}
            </option>
          </ng-template>
        </select>

        <input class="form-control" kendoTextBox />
        <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="removePhone(i)">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <a style="cursor:pointer" (click)="addPhone()">Add Phone</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Component.ts

```
  public phoneList = [
      {Name: 'Office Phone'},
      {Name: 'Facility Phone'},
      {Name: 'Fax'}
    ];

    contactForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  ...
  ...
  ...


  public addPhone() {
    if (this.phoneArraylength <= 3) {
      const phoneControl = new FormControl(null);
      (<FormArray>this.contactForm.get('secondaryPhone')).push(phoneControl);
      this.phoneArraylength++;
    }
  }

  get phoneFormArray() {
    return this.contactForm.get('secondaryPhone') as FormArray;
  }

  public removePhone(index: number) {
    this.phoneFormArray.removeAt(index);
    this.phoneArraylength--;
  }
```

I am new to angular so i might dont know some of its features so is there a proper way where i can show dynamic options in dynamically built dropdowns with same data source?

Answer (score 0):

Since datasource is an object array, you can just make an temp object array of same type that you move the values to by using `splice()` on datasource array during any `change` event. Then if you change value in the dropdown (e.g from Home to Mobile) you just use `splice()` on the temp array.

Comment: I tried this but removing a value from data source removes selected option (lets say "Home" ) from the first Drop down too

Comment: @Umer ok so your dropdowns are created dynamically but does your data (Fax, Home, Mobile, etc) do the same? In that case you could create an array of arrays of objects and use the array element of index equal to your `'ngFor`. Then when you select an object in that array element you remove the identical object from the other array elements (in the array of arrays).